# JQuery is not rendered Thymeleaf -> Flying-Saucer -> PDF

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I have implemented Flying-Saucer inside my existing Spring Application. The template is rendered with Thymeleaf and then converted from HTML to xHTML with Tidy. Inside the template I want to add some `JQuery` code to color a `td` red if the value inside the `div` is less than 0.

I'm using the following HTML structure:

```
<table class="dcf">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>-500</span> €
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>-500</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>-500</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>10.00,00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>-5.000,23</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>5.000,23</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>5.000,23</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>5.000,23</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dcf").find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).find("span").html()) < 0) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
      }
    })
  });

})
```

here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e51rynjx/2/

Here is my Java implementation:

```
SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(appContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/pdf/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8);

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(data);

        String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process("bm001", context);
        String xHtml = convertToXhtml(renderedHtmlContent);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        String baseUrl = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src", "main", "resources").toUri().toURL().toString();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml, baseUrl);
        renderer.layout();

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
```

Why is the JQuery not executed before the xHTML is exported to PDF? As far as I understand the rendering of the HTML should be handled by Thymeleaf. So why is the JavaScript never executed?

Comment: Think you'll find that iText does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: Check the limitations of Flying Saucer at https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html. `Scripting (e.g. JavaScript) is not supported. We ignore script tags. This could probably be added, at least for simple cases (e.g. JS that doesn't modify the DOM) by hooking in calls to the Rhino JS implementation.`

Comment: Is there an alternative that renders JavaScript? Or is there a workaround to execute the JavaScript code in Thymeleaf?